# What's the difference between PATH_NOT_FOUND and NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

In Win32 layer, we often meet `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_NAME_NOT_FOUND`.

When does `WinAPI(eg CreateFileW, RemoveDirectoryW)` return these values?
And What's the difference?

If I write a file system driver, when do I set `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND` or `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`?

How do you determine?

I'm so confused.
Is there anyone who can explain clearly?
Or are there any documents explain this? I couldn't find them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ERROR_NAME_NOT_FOUND` is not a standard Win32 API error code.  Typical errors returned by file related APIs that take a file name are `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.  The best way to figure out what error code to return is use a WDK sample as a guide.  The cdfs sample's `create.c` source code file for example.  It returns `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND` if it cannot locate a directory, `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` if it cannot locate a file.

Comment: fast! clear! Thanks Hans. -ERROR_NAME_NOT_FOUND was my mistake :)